# how do I prevent from the actual pytorch model not to be converted to ipex

Tags: python, pytorch, quantization, intel-pytorch

I have been trying out intel extension for pytorch([ipex](https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-pytorch)) to optimise my inference. I am using a pretrained model from torchvision.  I wanted to compare improvement with and without ipex so I created a copy of model converted it to ipex.

Now I try to do inference with, both my original model and the model converted to ipex.

For the model converted to ipex I have no issues but for my original model I get the below error.

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (XPUFloatType) should be the same
```

This error looks like due to my actual model also getting converted to ipex how do I prevent from the actual model ie model_original not to be converted to ipex

Below is a minimum reproducer.

```
import intel_pytorch_extension as ipex
import torchvision
import torch
import torch.utils.data as Data
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
model_original=model                             #original pytorch model which does not use ipex
model_ipex=model        
model_ipex.to(ipex.DEVICE)                         # a copy of a model converted to use IPEX
transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
        torchvision.transforms.Resize((500, 400)),
        torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
        torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
            root='dataset',
            transform=transform,
    )
loader = Data.DataLoader(
            dataset=dataset,
            batch_size=1
    )

for data, target in loader:              #inference with ipex this works fine
    print(target)
    output=model_ipex(data)
    
for data, target in loader:             #inference with original model this fails
    print(target)
    output=model_original(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to assign a pytorch model to a new variable as in your code `model_ipex=model` the copying is done with a **shallow copy** so your model and model_ipex point to the same memory. Which means any change you make in the copy of the model,  model_original also change. Which means you offload the model to use ipex with `model_ipex.to(ipex.DEVICE)` your original model is also offloaded and the weights of your model become of `XPUFloatType` datatype to which you are trying to pass an input of `torch.FloatTensor` which causes the issue.

If you need to have to separate copies of the model you should consider using  **deep copy**.

```
import copy
model_copy = copy.deepcopy(model)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator in python acts like "tag" a new name to an object (just a comparison or description), which is named as *shallow copy*. You can call `resnet50`'s constructor again to create a different object, and convert one of two created objects to ipex.